# Chip antenna design guide

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, antenna, layout

In a board which incorporates a Sub-1GHz transceiver (CC1310) I want to add a chip antenna. I found out that this anntena suits very much to my chip.

https://www.johansontechnology.com/datasheets/antennas/0900AT43A0070.pdf

I scrutinized the datasheet but I wasn't able to find in what rules the antenna's tail trace must be routed. There's a recommendation layout at the page 2 of 8 and an alternative of it at page 7 of 8. But, regarding theirs shape, I can't spot any relation between them. Besides that, the length doesn't seem to be the same.

Although, I searched a lot through the internet, I haven't found anything regarding that "tail trace". How am I suppose to re-route that tail in my board if I can't afford the space to make it looks exactly like the datasheet?

Has anyone ever seen similar design like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend changing the layout of the antenna from the ones shown in the datasheet.

RF antenna design is a very complex subject that require expertise and usually extensive simulation to tune the antenna parameters and meet the transmission standard requirements. Admittedly, it is not my field, but I've seen some approved PCB antenna designs that made me honestly question if they would work at all and how such wierd shape was even conceived.

I suggest you to treat the space occupation of the antenna just like any other specification. If this one does not fit, I would to look for another one instead of trying a reshape that would change and probably kill its performance.